# CSS url() not accepting URLs with end slashes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a background image using an image URL. When I use, for example, (https://www.pexels.com/photo/black-suv-on-snow-covered-ground-11001379/) the image doesn't show , but when I use (https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/hd-wallpaper-1.jpg) the image does.

I have no idea why this happens.

```
.container {

 background: linear-gradient(transparent 10%, #20283c 90%), url("https://www.pexels.com/photo/black-suv-on-snow-covered-ground-11001379/") no-repeat;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-attachment: "fixed";
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: As others have pointed out the URL you are using is to a website. pexel seems to be a service which allows you to download images and then use them as you like. I can't entirely make out whether it is happy for you to use it as a server of images instead - I think it might but note it has an API for this which requires a key, and it also asks you to contact them if you have a high usage site - best to read the terms of use and make sure you are not violating any conditions. Or just download the image and upload it to your own site, you know the image is available always then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
https://www.pexels.com/photo/black-suv-on-snow-covered-ground-11001379/
```

Is not an image URL, it's a website.

The image URL of the actual image is ...

```
https://images.pexels.com/photos/11001379/pexels-photo-11001379.jpeg
```

The url property needs a url pointing to an actual image file.

Comment: Please make sure that you are following the terms of use of the pexel site.

Answer (score 0):

Choose
background-image: url();

Comment: This does not make any difference and does not solve the problem - the problem being that the url being used is not the url of an image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`https://www.pexels.com/photo/black-suv-on-snow-covered-ground-11001379/` is a website,
[image]
A website contains many images, coding and ads. Just like the website you're going to make!
To get the actual URL

- Right-click the image, and select `Copy Image Link`
  [image]

The link copied to the clipboard will be

```
https://images.pexels.com/photos/11001379/pexels-photo-11001379.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260
```

here the parts after `?` are not needed so trim them

```
https://images.pexels.com/photos/11001379/pexels-photo-11001379.jpeg
```

Of Course, your trimmed part has an ending with `.jpeg`, or `.png`...in our case its `.jpeg`, and that makes it work

Comment: Thanks a ton! It helped me understand it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
background: linear-gradient(transparent 10%, #20283c, 90%), url("https://www.pexels.com/photo/black-suv-on-snow-covered-ground-11001379/" ) no-repeat;

background: #ffffff url("img_tree.png") no-repeat right top;
```

Please put the picture from your computer

Answer (score 0):

si quieres especificar que el fondo de tu pagina puedes agregar esta propuedada en el css

```
background-image: url("aqui agregas la direccion que nececitas");
```